# Writing a recursive function in C for the formula a(0) + 1/(a(1) + 1/(a(n-2) + 1/(a(n-1))))

Tags: c, recursion

I need to write a recursive function in C, the problem being this formula:

[image]

And I cannot make it work for all test cases, I am lost in trying to debug it and would appreciate if someone would help me and tell me where I am mistaken.

I tried running this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float calculateExpression(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
   
    if (start == end)
        return arr[start];

    
    return 1.0 / (calculateExpression(arr, start, end - 1) + 1.0 / calculateExpression(arr, end, end));
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int arr[n];
   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    float result = calculateExpression(arr, 0, n - 1);
    printf("%f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

But my it only works in some test cases, like for example when the input is 3 0 3 2.

Comment: Can you give some examples of test cases, what your expected result is, and the result you actually got?

Comment: @Chris For example this is a test case I had:
The input was:
7 3 7 15 1 292 1 1
The expected output is:
3.141593
My output is:
0.819970
Other test case:
Input:
50 50 8 43 32 29 4 23 26 17 16 30 16 20 42 41 24 36 27 38 43 22 10 27 14 48 21 20 40 36 13 10 28 33 3 8 3 6 49 23 23 12 31 37 33 12 47 32 42 16 1
Expected output:
50.124638
My output:
0.474554
I don't think my function is working properly but I don't really know what to change.

Comment: The formula says that the answer is `a[0] + 1.0 / something`. And the `something` is `a[1] + 1.0 / otherthing`, where `otherthing` is `a[2] + 1.0 / yetanotherthing`. Eventually, you get to the base case, which you've implemented correctly. In short, there should be one recursive call in your function, not two.

Comment: There is no need for recursion here. It can be evaluated from the inside-out with no need for function calls.

Answer (score 2):

You are never adding your first element of the array in the final answer. That is why it's working for test cases where the first element is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The general case for `calculateExpression` is wrong. It should return `arr[start]` plus the reciprocal of the recursive case, which is `calculateExpression(arr, start+1, end)`, not `calculateExpression(arr, start, end-1)`. There is no reason for it to call `calculateExpression` twice.

`calculateExpression` can be:

```
float calculateExpression(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    return arr[start] + (start == end ? 0 : 1/calculateExpression(arr, start+1, end));
}
```

or, better yet, just use the pointer to the array as the start point:

```
float calculateExpression(int *p, int n)
{
    return *p + (n ? 1/calculateExpression(p+1, n-1) : 0);
}
```

and change the initial call to `calculateExpression(arr, n-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got part of the recursion right. You have a base case that stops the recursion. What you're not getting quite right is the convergence on that base case.

If we're not at the end of the array, we need to add the current element to `1.0` divided by calling `calculateExpression` on the remainder of the array, which we address by incrementing `start` by one in the recursive call.

```
float calculateExpression(int arr[], int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) 
        return arr[start];

    return arr[start] + 
        1.0 / calculateExpression(arr, start+1, end);
}
```

Comment: There is no need for recursion here. It can be evaluated from the inside-out with no need for function calls.  The recursion may be easier to understand, but it comes at a heavy price.

Comment: Another option would be to rewrite this for tail recursion, and use a compiler that does TCO.

Comment: If in fact it could be structured for tail recursion, which is probably not possible.  In any case, it's usually a mistake to deliberate write recursive code with the expectation that the compiler will remove the recursion.  High-level optimizations like that are usually best when made directly in the source code.  It's also much easier to debug code that hasn't been significantly restructured by a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution i came up with. it checks out with your sample outputs.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double calculate_expr(int *arr, int *end){
    if(arr == end)
        return *(arr);

    return *(arr++) + 1.0/calculate_expr(arr, end);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", arr + i);

    double result = calculate_expr(arr, arr + n - 1);
    free(arr);
    printf("%lf\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

like some others have mentioned, the solution only requires one recursive call.

Comment: The use of the post increment operator feels unnecessarily "clever" and leaves the function dependent on The left hand side of the addition being evaluated first.

Comment: @Chris I suppose "dependent" is a euphemism for "vulnerable" :-p

Comment: hey @Chris, i wasn't trying to be clever but this is how i've been writing code for sometime now. I'm only a sophomore in college. I chose this method because "the order of evaluation of the operands of the addition operator is guaranteed to be from left to right in C". If you could tell me how i could've written it better, and why I would want to change it given the C guarantee, i will have learnt something useful. thanks!

Comment: A couple of additional notes: `int main(void)`; check the return value of `scanf`; you don't need to cast the result of `malloc`; and you _may_ not need to use dynamic allocation, if your compiler implements variable length arrays.